# How can I label my build with revision number and not the GUID (in TeamCity)?

Tags: mercurial, teamcity

I am trying to do "continuous integration" with TeamCity. I would like to label my builds in a incremental way and the GUID provided by the VCS is not as usefull as a simple increasing number. I would like the number to actually match the revision in number in Mercurial.

My state of affairs:

[image]

Mercurial info:

[image]

I would like the build to be labeled 0.0.12 rather than the GUID.

Would someone be so kind and save me hours of trying to figure this out ?

Comment: You sure you want to do that?

All it takes is someone pushing a branch to your repository and those revision numbers change.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As Lasse V. Karlsen mentioned those numerical revision numbers are local-clone specific and can be different for each clone.  They're really not suitable for versioning -- you could reclone the same repo and get different revision numbers.

At the very least include the node id also creating something like `0.0.12-6ec760554f2b` then you still get sortable release artifacts but are still firmly identifying your release.

If you're using numeric tags to tag releases there's a particularly nice option:

```
% hg log -r tip --template '{latesttag}.{latesttagdistance}'
```

which, if the most recent tag on that clone was called `1.0.1` and was `84` commits ago gives a value like:

```
1.0.1.84
```

Since you can have different heads that are 84 commits away from a tag in different repos you should still probably include the node id like:

```
% hg log -r tip --template '{latesttag}.{latesttagdistance}-{node|short}'
```

giving:

```
1.0.1.84-ec760554f2b
```

which makes a **great** version string.

Comment: How did you get information into TeamCity though? I still don't see a way to get that info into a system property so that it can be used in naming things like artifacts.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question, as it does not relate to Teamcity

Answer (score 13):

The best and easiest way to see rev. number in TeamCity build number is to use [Build Script Interaction with TeamCity](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity). Namely, it has a possibility to [set Build Number](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildNumber).

So, add to your project a new very first build step Command Line with following Command Executable

```
for /f %%i in ('c:\tortoisehg\hg id -n') do echo ##teamcity[buildNumber '%%i']
```

And you will get the Mercurial revision number as a label for your every build.

Of course you can change the command in quotes to anything you wish.

*I believe my answer is way more correct than the accepted one.*

**EDIT:**

Also you can do the same via MSBuild task rather than Command Executable. Have a MSBuild project file with following code, setup TeamCity to run it as first step, and it will alter its global variable `buildNumber`:

```
<Message Text="##teamcity[buildNumber '$(CurrentVersion)']" Importance="High" />
```

Where `CurrentVersion` is a string containing full version (for example "1.0.56.20931").

Comment: Dear George, that is why I stated "you can change the command line in quotes". For example you could read a file like so 'cat version.txt'. Put some fantasy on it, my friend.

Comment: Also I have never said 'my answer is the best', George. Let me repeat what I said: 'my answer is way more correct'. Because it answers the initial question unlike the accepted answer.

Comment: Your answer, while being technically correct, is misguiding for one who wants to build a system with possibility to identify change-sets by build numbers which might be an intention in original question.

Comment: Exactly! "Which **might be** an intention". But it is not. :) The straight question got straight answer assuming nothing else but question in place. Cheers, my friend. ;)

Answer (score 6):

`hg id` produces the hash (`6ec760554f2b`), `hg id -n` produces the local revision number (`12`).

(Note this is an answer purely from the hg side, how you then get that into TeamCity, I don't know, as I've never used it.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The adding to the TeamCity will be the unknown.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to use it in Teamcity using a workaround:

```
    <Exec Command="hg log -r tip --template {latesttag}.{latesttagdistance} > $(BuildAgentTempDir)\version.txt"/>
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(BuildAgentTempDir)\version.txt">
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="versionInfo"/>
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <TeamCitySetBuildNumber BuildNumber="@(versionInfo)-{build.number}" />
```

If you see the MSBuild task "TeamCitySetBuildNumber" I'm using the "{build.number}" variable because it substitutes this with what you set in the build number originally. I used %build.vcs.number% in my original settings (in the Web UI) and the result is just what Ry4an wrote above!

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Great! So, you've added Build Step into beginning of tasks queue? Do I need to install anything to use MSBuild tasks ReadLinesFromFile and ReadLinesFromFile?

Comment: Could you please explain where i need to put this BuildStep? I am using TeamCity 6.5. Do i need to setup the SetVersion BuildFeature? Thx in advanced.

Comment: @ChrisTTian667 how are you configuring your build in Teamcity? Do you use a SLN file or a custom-made MSBuild project?

Answer (score 3):

When I used to use Subversion I used to do something similar in TeamCity. The format was:

```
{Major}.{Minor}.{TeamCity Build No.}.{Subversion Revision No.}
```

This allowed me to look at an assembly and see which build it came from on TeamCity and the revision number from subversion.

I have now moved to Git which has put me in the same situation as you. After playing with various ideas I have come to the conclusion that I don't actually need the revision, the build is good enough. Because TeamCity is such a powerful tool, all you need is the build number, given the build number you can look at the build history and determine the revision from that.

```
{Major}.{Minor}.{Macro}.{TeamCity Build No.}
```

Additionally you can get TeamCity to label your repository with the build number allowing you to look up a given build in your source control.

Answer (score 2):

When providing your build number with numeral mercurial revision, you must be aware, that those numbers are clone-specific and can differ from clone to clone.

In our project we had the same issue. We're using TeamCity 7.1.1. We solved it in the following way:

1. Add Command line build step to your configuration.
2. Make this build step run first.
3. In the build step properties select "Run: 'Executable with parameters'"
4. Add the following text to Command Executable:

`for /f %%i in ('hg id -n') do echo ##teamcity[buildNumber '%%i']`

```
 Save changes.
```

You can also use previously generated build number when performing step 3.

**Example:**

```
for /f %%i in ('hg id -n') do echo ##teamcity[buildNumber '%system.build.number%.%%i']
```

*You can use this to make build counter present in your build number.*

Read [this](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildNumber) to get more information!

Remember that teamcity compiles configurations build number before build starts ***and the correct build number will appear only after your build step will finish its job.*** That's why, in some cases (f.e. inserting your mercurial revision into artifact's name) you should define build number's value in preceding configuration and refer to it.

**Example:**

```
%dep.bt82.build.number%
```

Read [this](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/How+To...#HowTo...-Sharethebuildnumberforbuildsinachainbuild) to get more information!

Comment: How exactly are you running an HG command?  Did you install a TC build client agent on the server that TC server is running?  TC never downloads the .hg directory onto agents.