# How to use %teamcity.build.checkoutDir% path-variable (win7) in an ant script

Tags: ant, teamcity

i am trying to use the %teamcity.build.checkoutDir% variable in my ant script to build a custom path to a file which gets passed as parameter to another program called via ant exec job.

```
<exec executable="${props.tools.vbpUpdater}" failonerror="true" >
        <arg line="-c${vbpConfigLocal} ${teamcity.agent.checkoutDir}/${vbpFile}" /> 
</exec>
```

The format of the path seems to be off.
What i get is :

```
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent
```

What i expected is something like this

```
C:\\TeamCity\\buildAgent or C:/TeamCity/buildAgent
```

If i add a custom property to my build agent with the expected format (i did this for testing purposes only) everything works fine in my ant script.

best regards

Comment: Have you tried ${teamcity.agent.checkoutDir}\${vbpFile}

Comment: Yes, but doesn't work either, today i'll try the <replace /> task from ant i read about over the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this instructions](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-AddingorChangingaBuildParameter) and create a build step (it should be the first one in queue) which would replace '/' with the values you need. And in further build step use this modified value.

I've done some similar things when [integrating mercurial build number into build version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16701554/1685878)